# Git Workflow for developing features using multiple branches

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, git-branch

I have an app that I've augmented with extra debugging features which make it easier for me to develop.
 However , I can't commit these changes. So I need a way to implement my feature on the "augmented" branch ,
 and then when I'm finally done, push it to master.

There are the two workflows that I've found : -

**Workflow # 1:**

```
  1. Checkout augmented branch 
  2. Make changes
  3. Stash the changes
  4. Switch to master
  5. Apply the stash and resolve conflicts
  6. Commit and push to master
```

**Workflow # 2:**

```
  1. Checkout augmented branch
  2. Make changes
  3. Switch branches using git checkout -m
  4. Check everything is fine and commit to master
```

And for both the workflows I rebase changes from master onto the "augmented" branch so that everything stays upto date.

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of ? Is there any better way ?

Comment: Pitfall to be aware of: someday, you'll need those debugging features in production or SIT, and you and your boss will wish you'd just merged them to master.

Comment: In that case we can just rebase it on to master no ?

Comment: erm.. Why not set a system property `logging=info` and read that in. Because if it breaks in prod - flicking `logging=debug` even for a couple of seconds is a lifesaver. In case its java - try `log4j`. Apologies if that was off-topic, in my team we have lot of development going on, people cannot commit to `master`. `master` must match production all the time. Changes can only be merged into `master` at the point of going into production. Before merging to `master`, merge into an integration stream where other people have also merged. Test and then selectively merge into `master`.

Comment: Its not just logging .. its a newer javascript pre processor which is more picky than the earlier so lot of the code needs to be changed so that it compiles. But once that is done the error messages are much better. However its hard to convince the rest to switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need a way to implement my feature on the "augmented" branch , and then when I'm finally done, push it to master.

That would be rebasing your "`augmented_branch`" regularly on top of `master` (since you are the only one working with that branch).

Once you have convinced the rest of the team of using your version, a merge to `master` will be a simple fast-forward merge.

Comment: If I do that won't the other committed changes on the augmented branch also get applied to master ? I dont want that to happen.

Comment: @eddardstark no, a rebase will keep your "`augmented_branch`" commit isolated. master won't be aware of those commits.